# How do i test content-scripts in chrome extensions automatically?

Tags: javascript, testing, google-chrome-extension, continuous-integration

I programmed a chrome extension which parses various site informations through content scripts. Now every other month one of the websites i support change their html layout, move to another address etc. And so i have to update my extension.

With 14 supported website (growing) with 5-7 properties each its just too much to do by hand. Is there a way to automatically run my js functions in the context of the websites and check the result?

I tryed it with iframes, but that didnt work cause of the same origin policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a test page within my extension. It's only accessible if you know the correct path.

This test page then opens all sites supported by my extension with `chrome.tabs.create` and then inserts my test code with `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. `executeScript` can return the test results which i then display on my test page.

Code:

- https://github.com/shylux/FocusManga/tree/v1.2.2/extension/testing.js (executes tests, renders results)
- https://github.com/shylux/FocusManga/tree/v1.2.2/extension/testing.html (output, template)
- https://github.com/shylux/FocusManga/tree/v1.2.2/extension/testing_hoster.js (data, expected results)

Comment: This is not good approach it you want to publish your extension because you need to remove this page before packaging the extension. And number of test pages are growing over time.

Comment: Why remove them? I know its good practice but tests can't do anything harmful. (extra extension is just too much work right now)
ATM i have 16 pages to test and it takes about 3 seconds. That's pretty good.
I added my code so you can take a look. Criticism appreciated :)

Comment: Why does end user need them? Also some tests require "hooks" to verify expected behavior correctness. Such hooks might affect normal extension flow. Do you really want to investigate any issues caused by this? BTW in my case tests take few hours to complete

Comment: The links are dead.

Comment: I removed the testing since i did it manually. I fixed the links so they are now pointing to a version where the files are still present. :)

Answer (score 1):

I created test extension for this. It navigates to the predefined list of pages and checked for expected modifications on each page (presence of specific tags). In your case it could be data tags with parsing results. Or you could share business logic code with your test extension and just adds additional validation code to it

Comment: sounds interesting. do you host your code somewhere so i can use it as reference?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is part of company codebase. I created separate page with runs test spec with jasmine right after load. In manual mode click on browser action icon opens this page. Automatic mode just navigates to this predefined page